# How to get UUID partition form a given file path in Python

Tags: python, uuid

How to get the UUID partition of a given file path in Python, in Ubuntu/Linux

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer working in bash:

```
file='/home/'
blkid -o value $(\df --output=source "$file"|tail -1)|head -1
```

In python

```
import os
def getUUID_from_path(filepath)
    return os.system("blkid -o value $(\df --output=source " + filepath + "|tail -1)|head -1")
```